# Can ActsAsTaggableOn allow multiple owners per tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm debating on whether I have to implement my own tagging system or use the great ActsAsTaggableOn gem. I'm unclear on whether ActsAsTaggableOn will allow more than one owners of the same tag.

I want multiple owners per tag because I'd like to show users a list of all the tags they own, even if they were not the first to enter them.

Does ActsAsTaggableOn work like this by default, or can only the first person to enter a new tag be the owner (one to one).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started using acts-as-taggable-on this week and have read the docs thoroughly, however, I have not yet needed to use the [tag owner](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-ownership) feature. With that being said, I can still assist based on my knowledge and experience thus far.

First, and foremost, you may not yet be aware of ActsAsTaggableOn's Tagging model. It is the join between the tag and the taggable objects. **Therefore, taggers can not own tags, they can own taggings.**

Here is an example of a taggings table...

[image: Here is an example of my taggings table]

The first record does not use the #tag method. For example, from the Github docs:

```
@some_user.tag(@some_photo, :with => "paris, normandy", :on => :locations)
```

The 2nd record does. So in the 2nd case, if multiple taggers could tag the same taggable object, then there would only be able to be one owner per tag.

NOTE:
After rereading [the tag owner feature](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-ownership) I think it is misleading a bit and may have been the reason for your question. It should really say ***Tagging* Ownership** or **Tag Ownership (Per Taggable Object)**. I think I may do a pull request and try to make that clearer.